# How can I solve this problem : tokenizers.BertWordPieceTokenizer error

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

I'm trying to Train BERT Language Model From Scratch On TPUs (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-3zts7FTDA) but I'm facing this problem :

```
bwpt = tokenizers.BertWordPieceTokenizer(
    vocab_file=None,
    add_special_tokens=True,
    unk_token='[UNK]',
    sep_token='[SEP]',
    cls_token='[CLS]',
    clean_text=True,
    handle_chines_chars=True,
    strip_accents=True,
    lowercase=True,
    wordpieces_prefix='##'
)
```

after run :

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-8eec5eb54376> in <module>
----> 1 bwpt = tokenizers.BertWordPieceTokenizer(
      2     vocab_file=None,
      3     add_special_tokens=True,
      4     unk_token='[UNK]',
      5     sep_token='[SEP]',

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'vocab_file'
```

I'm working on my PC, on Jupyter notebook
Tensorflow 2.4.1
Tokenizer 0.10.1
Transformers 4.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an API mismatch due to a renaming in `BertWordPieceTokenizer`. Most likely `vocab_file` was renamed to `vocab`.

See: https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers/blob/ee95e7f0cd0defac6f055d02abd103c40d6c7194/bindings/python/py_src/tokenizers/implementations/bert_wordpiece.py#L14-L27